# What is the best way to migrate only profiles in Salesforce?

Tags: profile

We are getting issues while migrating only profiles. When we are trying to migrate through force.com IDE its fetching blank profiles as not object is chosen.

Is there any way by which we can easily transfer only profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Profile metadata is dependent on lot of other components .Hence no surprise you are not able to form the proper metadata XML without the objects .

I would suggest you to retrieve everything and go through the metadata to understand dependencies of profile .

If you want to just System permissions to be transferred ,you can use changesets and move and if you want to move other permissions which has dependency on other objects ,you will have to include the other dependent metadata to properly migrate .

Answer (score 0):

Change sets. You will have to move the objects as well though, as well as anything inside the profile you want moved.

Salesforce treats profiles like a junction object, so you have to include the objects for the profiles to reference. That is why you are getting blank profiles.